How to do field injection in a base class with Hilt in Android
I have this basic scenario where a base class needs to be injected with a Logger class. I am getting kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property logger has not been initialized in the location mentioned below. What am I missing? (note: constructor injection works but want to avoid adding logger to subclass constructors.
@Singleton
open class BaseRepository(private val userService: UserService) {
    @Inject lateinit var logger: Logger
    
    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            userService.flow.collectLatest {
                logger.setUserId(it?.userId) <-- EXCEPTION FROM HERE
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}


@Singleton
class HomeRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val homeService: HomeService,
    userService: UserService,
) : BaseRepository(userService) {
...
}

@Singleton
class LibraryRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val libraryService: LibraryService,
    userService: UserService,
) : BaseRepository(userService) {
...
}


Have you checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817973/8465878. It says, you need to use @EntryPoint to do field injection for custom classes.

Hey you can take a look at my library https://github.com/dewantawsif/flexible-hilt. After the setup you'll be able to do
open class BaseRepository(private val userService: UserService) {
    val logger: Logger = getFromFlexibleHilt()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            userService.flow.collectLatest {
                logger.setUserId(it?.userId) <-- EXCEPTION FROM HERE
            }
        }
    }
}

Also adding @Singleton annotation to BaseRepository won't do anything since you are manually initializing the class and not getting it from dagger hilt.

By using the "isInitialized" method, for checking if the lateinit variable is initialized or not.
can check this link too
https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-check-if-a-lateinit-variable-has-been-initialized
Hope this helps.
